# Does FPV transmitter antenna need to match the goggle receiver antenna?

Tags: antenna, video-transmitters, video-signal

So for a Fatshark, do I need to have both FPV transmitter and receiver antennas to be of the same brand and same specs? What about for a DJI goggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, specific brand and specs don't matter for interoperability (*aside from making sure that both antennae are built to transmit/receive the same frequency*). Specific specifications about an antenna can help you figure out which will work best for your use case, like the [antenna's gain](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/835/97), but mixing brands and types is fine.

However, there are certain mixes of antenna polarizations that will work better than others. You can learn more about this in *[Can circularly and linearly polarized antennae be used together for FPV?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/892/97)* and about what antenna polarization is in *[What is circular polarization in antennae?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/120/97)*.

Comment: Thank you for the  confirmation 

Comment: No problem, @DroneDome!